# Google Places Autocomplete API does not bias for location

Tags: google-places-api, google-places

I am using the Autocomplete API to get results 'biased' for current location with the following request:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=kuli&types=(regions)&key=[KEY]
```

The API returns the following response:

```
{
"predictions" : [
    {
        "description" : "Kulim Kedah Malaysia",
        ...
        "types" : [ "locality", "political", "geocode" ]
    },
    {
        "description" : "Kuliyapitiya, North Western Province, Sri Lanka",
        ...
        "types" : [ "locality", "political", "geocode" ]
    },
    {
        "description" : "Kulithalai, Tamil Nadu, India",
        ...
        "types" : [ "locality", "political", "geocode" ]
    },
    {
        "description" : "Kuligów, Poland",
        ...
        "types" : [ "locality", "political", "geocode" ]
    },
    {
        "description" : "Kulin, Western Australia, Australia",
        ...
        "types" : [ "locality", "political", "geocode" ]
    }
],
"status" : "OK"
}
```

As you can see above, the response does not bias for location. The doc says that the IP Address is taken into account when returning "near" locations. But from the response, the Indian locations are not returned first over others (The request IP address is Indian).

Even, when I pass location parameter with lat,long, as:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=kuli&types=(regions)&location=lat,long&key=[KEY]
```

still the Indian results are not prioritized over other response.

How do I make the API return location 'biased' over IP address or location coordinates? Thank you for your time.

Answer (score -1):

Add components to your url: `&components=country:IN`

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=kuli&components=country:IN&types=(regions)&location=lat,long&key=[KEY]
```

Comment: Thank you Subbu. But I do not want to constrain the search to a specific country. I just want the API to return "closer" place at the top of the search result.

Comment: Add types and radius "&types=geocode&location=latitude,longitude&radius=1000&sensor=true" for more details https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete#location_biasing